# What is Spring security best strategy for session authentication

Tags: spring-security, spring-social

I have a Spring MVC web application, there are no secure areas so all users can see all pages however i do have a Facebook log, using spring social,  in and i do identify each user by session id. the scenario is that a user can see pages as a guest where the application identify him (or her) by the session id, when the user log in with his (or hers) Facebook account, a record is save for the user with the corresponding Facebook data.
the next time the user visit the application i want to be able to identify him.
i thought about using spring security remember me feature (and an infrastructure for maybe future use).

so my question is, is spring security the right solution for me? and if so is it possible to set authentication by session id?

Answer (score 0):

Spring security is good for authenticating users. If you were just to authenticate by session id, there is the possibility that bogus users could access user info by spoofing their session data.